# Prove that $B(-1,r)\cap (-1,1)$ is non-empty for all $r>0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question is, how to prove mathematically that $B(-1,r)\cap (-1,1)$ is non-empty for all $r>0$? Here is $B(-1,r)$ the ball around $-1$ within $\mathbb{R}$. Intuitively, it is clear, as there is an interval $[-1,r)$ inside $B(-1,r)$ that will contain an element from $(-1,1)$. But is this guaranteed when $r$ is incredibly small (near $0$)? I can't seem to write the proof properly.

Here is an example to what I thought. Assume on the contrary that $B(-1,r)\cap (-1,1)$ is empty for some $r>0$. Should I choose an element $y\in (-1,1)$ to prove that $y$ is in fact in $B(-1,r)$ to reach contradiction? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply find the intersection and confirm that it isn't empty: since $B(-1,r)=(-1-r,-1+r)$, you have

$$B(-1,r)\cap(-1,1)=(-1-r,-1+r)\cap(-1,1)=(-1,\min\{-1+r,1\})$$

This is clearly not empty as long as $-1<-1+r$, which is true if $r>0$.

Comment: It's true for $r\leq 2$

Comment: @SacAndSac why should the statement only be true for $r\leq 2$? In my opinion it's true for all $r>0 as Vercassivelaunos proved

Comment: If $r>2$, $(-1-r,-1+r)\cap(-1,1)=(-1,1)$... It's just the statement : " the intersection is $(-1,-1+r)$ for all $r>0$" that is false

Comment: @SacAndSac ah sure I mean could he say $B(-1,r)\cap (-1,1)=\min\left\{(-1,-1+r),(-1,1)\right\}$ right? So for $r>2$ we get $(-1,1)$ which is clearly not empty and for $0<r\leq 2$ we get $(-1,-1+r)$ which is also non empty since $r>0$

Comment: Rather $B(-1,r)\cap(-1,1)=(-1,\inf\{-1+r,1\})$ but yes ;-)

Comment: @SacAndSac You're right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : take a point that depends on $r$: for example $\frac{-1+r}{2}$ (if $r< 3$, otherwise take the point $0$ for example).